# How much ionizing (carcinogenic) radiation is one exposed to on a commercial flight, what are the sources, and how could exposure be minimized?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, biophysics, absorption, cosmic-rays

I don't know if this is the best place to ask this question, but I figure a physics-based answer would be the most satisfying. I'd be happy to be convinced I'm being paranoid about protecting an infant from such increases in radiation too.

I'm wondering about radiation that could directly or indirectly mutate DNA sequences (X-rays, UV, gamma?).

I'm also wondering about feasible strategies to minimize this exposure  (particularly for preventing exposure to an infant). Would BoPET (Mylar) blankets or aluminum foil reflect such radiation? Would any material (that could feasibly be used to cover an infant) absorb the most problematic wavelengths?

Is the radiation at ~40,000 feet isotropic? Could there be some clever way to choose seats and orientations of any barriers (placing an infant between two parents?) to minimize exposure?

Comment: The word you want is not "carcinogenic", but "ionizing", not withstanding the ionizing radiation is a cancer risk. And most of the dose is in charged particles, not photons so there is basically nothing you can do about it.

Comment: [Here](http://www.cdc.gov/niosh/topics/aircrew/cosmicionizingradiation.html) is what the CDC has to say about this topic, for air crews. It covers all of the bases; note that your exposure is the same no matter where you sit, or what you wear.

Comment: You can "not fly", and that's pretty much all there is. If you are very rich, you can get your own plane with a heavy lead shield, but it wouldn't do much, either. Here is another answer from a sister site: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15823/how-much-radiation-is-an-airline-pilot-exposed-to-in-a-year

Comment: I will try to convince you that you are being paranoid.  There is no question that the dose of ionising radiation you get when flying is above that you get at ground level in general and that this is, realistically, unavoidable.  What is more important is whether it is harmful.  Well, it turns out that this is an study that is easy to do, because there is a large group of people who fly a lot: aircrew.  And the study has been done and no, it's not harmful: there's no significantly raised risk of cancer among aircrew.

Comment: @tfb Although not very drastic, aren't there studies that indicate some cancer increase? For example, http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/19608578/.

Comment: @jinawee I am unfortunately far away from the references I have (which are slightly biased themselves), but I believe the results are extremely inconclusive and small.  Indeed from the reference you gave 'Ionising radiation is considered to contribute little if at all to the elevated risks for cancers among aircrew, whereas excess ultraviolet radiation is a probable cause of the increased melanoma risk.' (Although I'd call UV ionising, I think?).  I guess my real claim is that if there is a risk it is much less than, say, driving to the airport.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about physics

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the body's exposure to an x-ray equal to an airplane trip across the country?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122827/is-the-bodys-exposure-to-an-x-ray-equal-to-an-airplane-trip-across-the-country)

Comment: If you worry about radiation, then worry about radon - not about a single plane ride. And worry more about the dangers of driving and texting, drunks on the road, and the risks of obesity. Worry about helping your child choose healthy friendships. Make sure to get fresh air, exercise, and everything in moderation. Radiation on planes should not be on your list or risks to mitigate.

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks for your feedback. Would the question be about physics if I asked for mSv and for specific wavelengths? Still curious about the sources, but maybe that is more of an astronomy question than physics?

Answer (score 0):

background radiation is very dependent on where you live it's different depending on altitude rocks around where you live ect. but generally comes to around 0.1 - 2 micro sieverts per hour the "ionizing radiation regulations 1999" states:

1. Anyone under 18 should not be exposed to more than 6 milli sieverts per year above background radiation ~ 1 micro sievert per hour.
2. An unborn fetus should not be exposed to more than 1 milli sievert for the duration of pregnancy above background radiation ~ 0.3 micro sieverts per hour.

A flight can add a temporary increase in radiation exposure to up to 5 milli sieverts per hour but for a single flight this will have a lot less impact than simply living in the wrong place for a week. It's also worth noting that all of these regulations are several orders of magnitude lower than the lowest radiation exposure linked to any increased chance of cancer or radiation related illness. If you fly very regularly you might you might go over the sugested limit but a one off wont make a difference.